# How do I make my Bot Ignore messages from people with a certain role? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

How can I make my **Discord.py** bot ignore messages from people that have a certain role?

I have recently added a feature that to my **Discord.py** bot.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == "Blocked Word":
        await message.delete()
```

I want it so that if someone such has myself, has a certain role the bot will not delete the message.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can get a list of the member roles using `message.author.roles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some simple code, that might answer your question:
This builds on @Joshua Nixon's answer

```py
@client.event()
async def on_message(message):
 if 'role' in [role.name for role in message.author.roles]: #checks if the specified role is in the user's roles
   #do something
 else:
   #do something else
```